# What is the etymology of “business” and “busyness”?

Tags: etymology

Did the word *business* originally mean “the condition of being busy” as the word *busyness* currently means?

Why did it change? It was surely a very useful word, since the awkwardly-spelt word *busyness* has had to be created to take its place.

I think I’m right in saying the *i-ness* construction is favoured above the *y-ness* construction in all other similar words – e.g. *happiness*, *friendliness*, *haziness*, *merriness*.

What really confuses is me is this: *Busyness* means **now** what *business* meant **then**. Why change an existing word, then create a similar one which means what the old one did? Why not just create a new word? I suspect there’s a story there, and I wonder what it is.

Comment: This is in danger of being closed as general reference: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/business

Comment: @Andrew Leach Please can you specify which part of your link you think answers my question.

Comment: Definition 1 answers the first question; the others are surely "It changed to differentiate *business* (a function or commercial activity) from *busyness* (the state of being busy)"; and you have answered the last one yourself!

Comment: The history of the word is long and complex and not susceptible to a brief summary here. If you're really interested in the etymology of this and other words, I recommend you subscribe to the Oxford English Dictionary: http://www.oed.com/

Comment: @Andrew But that is not right. Busyness means _now_ what business meant _then_. Why change an existing word, then create a similar one which means what the old one did? Why not just create a new word. That's what I'm asking. I'll clarify that in my question.

Comment: @Barrie Fair enough. I just thought it might be summarisable here. I found it rather curious. I'll wait a while longer, then remove the question if I get no answers.

Comment: Your edit makes clear what the real question is. I don't have access to OED; let's see if someone who does can precis the history.

Comment: Trivially answered with a single reference book, clearly doesn't meet the quality bar for SE sites.

Comment: @Nathan So.... one guy says it's too complex. Another says it's too trivial. Hmm... I'd say that makes it a perfect question.

Comment: Using other people's opinion of what is a good question rather than reading the rules and reasoning for yourself is part of what's wrong with this SE site.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business has all of the information he wants.  It took me one google search using obvious terms. Clearly this question doesn't meet the quality of a standards of a Stack Exchange Q&A, however since it's a democracy we're all more than welcome to vote ourselves into irrelevancy.

Comment: @Nathan C.Tresch Your link _fails_ to answer my question. 10 upvotes and no downvotes for the question seems to suggest you're in the minority thinking it's not meeting standards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> “Why change an existing word, then create a similar one which means what the old one did? Why not just create a new word?”

Because, with very few exceptions indeed, language development is not done by a planning committee. Language evolves over time.

According to OEtmD, [*business*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=business) is the modern spelling of the Old English *bisignes* “care, anxiety, occupation,” from *bisig* “careful, anxious, busy, occupied, diligent”. The meaning of this word eventually evolved to “occupation” and then “trade”. Thoreau may have been the one to coin the modern word [*busyness*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=busyness) to mean “being busy”; he is given credit for the first use of it in 1849.

*(This question reminds me of the story I read in an economics book, probably by David D. Friedman or Steven Landsburg: The Russian bureaucrat responsible for setting factory prices for raw materials was visiting the US and asked to meet with his counterpart. He was dumbfounded by the response:* there isn’t one. *He simply could not imagine a stable situation in which commodity prices were not set by a bureau but instead somehow governed themselves.)*