# Why does Business read like busyness?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

This is a bit weird, but the word `business` reads like `busy-ness`, but it sounds like `biz-ness`.

- Why is that?
- What happened to the `i`?

Comment: Related: [What is the etymology of “business” and “busyness”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76379)

Comment: @J.R. I don't think its related, as I am just asking about the pronunciation of the word `business`.

Comment: It's certainly related, though not a full answer, and hence not a duplicate.

Comment: Well the answer on that question doesn't answer my question. And I can't see any resemblance in that question compared to mine. @RonanMurphy has answered my question - as it is a pronunciation issue.

Comment: @Kev - Even if **you** are not interested in that discussion, others who stumble across your question here might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason *business* looks like *busy* + *ness* is that that is precisely what it is; a noun formed from the adjective *busy* by adding the suffix *–ness*.

But this formation happened a long time ago. The word is found (spelled *bisignisse*) in Old English. Now, consider how Old English sounds very different to Modern English (or if you aren't already familiar with this, then consider that the first three lines of Beowulf are the sentence "Hwæt! We Gardena in geardagum þeodcyninga þrym gefrunon hu ða æþelingas ellen fremedon.") and that many words have changed in the meantime.

In the course of these changes, people slipped over the middle vowel, much like some people would pronounce "did you" as "didja".

This became so common, that it became the normal pronunciation. Compare how *forecastle* became *fo'c's'le*.

While some people spelled the word so as to reflect this (*busnes*, *bisnies*, *bisnes* are all examples found between the 15th and 17th century) and some used the apostrophe to reflect both the pronunciation and the earlier origin (*buis'ness*), many spellings continued to include the elided *i* or *y*, and eventually *business* became what is now considered the sole correct spelling.

There are dialects that include the middle vowel. In the case of some Irish dialects (most pronounce it as two syllables like most other dialects), the influence of the *guta cúnta* (a pronunciation rule in the Irish language where a "helper vowel" is sometimes inserted) means that some words are pronounced with an extra /ə/ between consonants, such as *film* being prounounced /fɪləm/ rather than /fɪlm/ as in most English dialects. As such, the general tendency toward eliding the vowel was more likely to be resisted. Alternatively, it could even be that both happened—the vowel was elided as with most English dialects, and then put back in again as with *film*.

Comment: Very good answer! I have heard many people say `fɪləm` instead of saying it like `fɪlm` - I always wondered why they say it that way :)

Comment: @Kevdog777, I see in your profile that you are from the Isle of Man. I understand that Manx doesn't have the auxiliary vowels, but does have a similar tendency to keep certain consonants apart, albeit with a vowel that is included in the spelling, so I'm not surprised to learn that the form of English there shares our /fɪləm/.

Comment: The fact is that unstressed vowels in English get reduced to [ə] or [ɨ] in most cases, and frequently deleted. The E in _clothed_, for instance, used to be pronounced, and occasionally it's marked _clothèd_ to indicate that the extra syllable is still needed for a special purpose, like poetry or prayer. So it's variable, and it varies. _Busy_, by contrast, has no unstressed vowels, since final high vowels are tense by default.

Comment: @JonHanna I'm currently in the Isle of Man, but I'm actually South African :p - so SA English is very similar to American English (how I see it).

Answer (score 1):

That's a pronunciation issue more than anything else. People now pronounce it 'bizness' in some parts of the world, but a lot of the UK and Ireland would still say 'biz-eh-ness', pronouncing the middle syllable.

Comment: Ah right, I'm from the UK, but don't hear it much, maybe cuz I'm so use to it.

Comment: You don't say why it is a pronunciation issue.

Comment: It's a pronunciation issue because anyone who says 'bizz-ness' is pronouncing it incorrectly. But Jon does give a nice answer above. Nicer than mine. Although I'm an Irishman who doesn't say 'fillum'.

Comment: @RonanMurphy: It's a pronunciation issue because it's about pronunciation. And anybody who says /'bɪznəs/ (as virtually all American English speakers do) is pronouncing it correctly. If you want to say it different, do. But you don't get to say what's correct for other people; sorry.

Comment: Those saying /ˈbɪznᵻs/, /ˈbɪznᵻs/ or /ˈbɪznᵻz/ are certainly correct, but then so to are you if you pronounce it /ˈbɪzənᵻs/ if that is how your dialect treats the word (as some in Ireland do). My point is though, that you don't really examine why this has come to pass, though there was a gap in my answer two that John Lawler's comment nicely filled in.

Comment: @JonHanna very true. I answered the description rather than the question title. Your answer is far better anyway! :)